# Periodic order-reversing homeomorphism in the unit interval

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I'm studying the [theorem of Kerekjarto](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303256.pdf) and it says:

"Let $f : I \to I$ be a periodic homeomorphism of the unit interval. If $f$ preserves the endpoints then $f$ is the identity map. If $f$ exchanges the endpoints then $f^2 = Id$ and $f$ is conjugate to the reflection map $x \to 1 − x$."

Note the meaning of *periodic* here: "We say that $f$ is periodic if there is an integer $n>0$ such that $f^n=Id$. The period of $f$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ with this property"

I can prove that if $f$ preserves the endpoints, then $f = Id$, but I can't find a solution to the other statement, that is, if $f$ is a periodic homeomorphism, $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$, then it $f(x) = 1 - x$. We know that $f$ is an involution and $f^2 = Id$

For example, it's easy to prove that if $f$ is linear, then $f$ must be $1-x$, but why should $f$ be linear?

Comment: The theorem states (in the second case) that $f$ is conjugate to $x\mapsto1-x$, not equal to $x\mapsto1-x$, so proving the latter won't be possible.

Comment: From the paper: "We say that $f$ is periodic if there is an integer $n > 0$ such that $f^n = Id$. The period of $f$ is the smallest positive integer n with this property" @LutzLehmann

Comment: @GregMartin How would you approach proving conjugacy instead of equality in this case?

Comment: @AlbertoCentelles You should edit your question to include the definition of "periodic".

Comment: Thank you @PaulFrost. Done

Answer (score 4):

In the case of the strictly decreasing $f$ with $f^2=Id$, the map $$h(x)=(x+1-f(x))/2$$ is a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ with $$h(f(x))=1-h(x).$$

You need to check that the used equivalency (for scalar real functions) of homeomorphic to continuous plus strictly monotonous holds.